# How to convert csv to JSON nested structure

Tags: json, csv, nested

I have a json file to store my data and I convert it to CSV to edit my data. But when i convert it to json again it all goes unconstructed. How can i convert my csv to same structure as my old json.

**JSON**

```
{
  "product": [
    {
      "id": "item0001",
      "category": "12",
      "name": "Name1",
      "tag": "tag1",
      "more": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "AL"
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "BS"
        }
      ],
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "id": "item0002",
      "categoryId": "13",
      "name": "Name2",
      "tag": "tag2",
      "size": "2",
      "more": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "DL"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "AS"
        }
      ],
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**CSV**

id,categoryId,name,shortcut,more/0/optionId,more/0/price,more/1/optionId,more/1/price,active,more/2/optionId,more/2/price,spanSize
item0001,ab92d2c6-010e-4182-844d-65050e746617,Name1,Shortcut1,1,60,1,70,TRUE,,,
item0002,ab92d2c6-010e-4182-844d-65050e746617,Name2,Shortcut2,2,60,2,70,TRUE,2,2,4

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: How do you convert it back to Json ? which tool or program... ?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit. Im using Windows Excel to edit my CSV

Comment: I'm using this to convert my csv to json https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/csv-to-json-converter/9wzdncrdhjct

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/) (mlr) to convert you file both ways

https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flatten-unflatten/

first from JSON to CSV

```
mlr --ijson --ocsv cat test.json > test.csv
```

then edit CSV ([Visidata](https://www.visidata.org/) is a very nice command line tool for the job)

then convert it back to CSV

```
mlr --icsv --ojson cat test.csv > test_v2.json
```

If you want to have some JSON lines structure instead, use `--ojonl`